# Как анимировать это изображение на html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть задание,нужно  подобный рисунок написать и анимировать на html/css. Каким образом это можно сделать,с чего начать и это вообще реально?

Comment: Еще наверное можно с помощью svg и анимировать. Но с векторной графикой не до конца понимаю, как после ней работать

Comment: Ну прям картинку нельзя) Можно сделать канвасом, пусть долго и сложно. Затем анимировать его. Хороший урок, в котором даже есть частичка вашего случая - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq2au9EfeRQ&ab_channel=ChrisCourses

А так - вполне реальная задача

Comment: Вам поможет webgl, я бы может и ответил с кодом, но вопрос прикрыли) в вопросе явно не хватает описания характера анимации